# Flutter Web and logging on iPhone

Tags: python, flutter, logging, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Web app with an iOS Safari-specific error. To debug it I create a build (`flutter build web`) and run Python's http.server (`python3 -m http.server`), then use `ngrok` to be able to open the app on my mobile device.

To be able to see logs I use `OverlayEntry` with `Text`, but it's not very convenient.

Python's http.server does some logging that looks like this:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
::1 - - [10/Sep/2022 20:05:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [10/Sep/2022 20:05:07] "GET /flutter.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Is it possible to log something from a Flutter app to see it inside Python's http.server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use print() to log something to the console. You can also use the dart:developer package to log to the browser's console. Example:

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
developer.log('Hello world!', name: 'my.app.category');
```